# Package installation does not work on Atom

Tags: web, npm, editor, atom-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI7gI.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF32N.png)

Bracket and VS Code work well
but, It doesn't work at Atom

this message:
(node:2460) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET https://www.atom.io/api/packages/emmet/versions/2.4.3/tarball

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\H.atom.apm_logs\2022-04-20T00_38_35_858Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site's down because I'm trying to download a package as well and it's not working, while my internet connection is working normally.

I'm trying to download atom-runner, for reference.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information, share the error you received.

Comment: It just worked as of one minute ago. Site looks to be back up!